# Is there a way to write text with emoji to Excel or Google Sheets?

Tags: r, excel, google-sheets, file-io

Is there a way to write text with emoji to Excel or Google Sheets? I have a dataframe like this, and I've tried `write.csv()` with the `fileEncoding` parameter set, but no luck.

```
df <- data.frame(number = c(1, 2),
                textEmoji = c("Test ",
                              "Test "))

write.csv(df, file="df.csv", row.names = FALSE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it to a `.xlsx` file:

```
rio::export(df, "test.xlsx")
```

[image]

I just checked and your approach with `write.csv()` works as well. The problem is just that Excel doesn't recognize the `"UTF-8"` apparently (it works when read back into `R`). Encoding is saved though in the `.xlsx` so Excel will displays that one properly.

Comment: Thanks for explaining about csv/Excel.